# Need to speed up function that is creating bigrams from a text list

Tags: r, nlp

I have a list of words that looks like this:

[[1]]
[1] "quick" "brown" "fox"   "jumps"

[[2]]
[1] "once"     "upon"     "midnight" "dreary"

[[3]]
[1] "quoth"     "raven"     "nevermore"

What I'm trying to do is create a set of bigrams based on this list (which is much, much larger than the example). My code is below, and it works. The problem is that it's too darn slow. I know my loop in bigram_list() is slowing it down, but I can't figure out how to use lapply with a list. I also suspect that data tables and rbindlist() would help a lot, but I can't seem to get them to work either. Any help will be met with choruses of hallelujahs.

```
bigram_list <- function(words, ng) {
    tokens <- character()

    words_length <- length(words)
    for (i in 1:words_length) {
        set <- words[[i]]          ##current vector of words
        end <- length(set)
        if (end > 2) {
            if (ng == 1) {
                nlist <- set[1:(end-1)]
            } else {
                nlist <- set[2:end]
            }
            tokens <- c(tokens,nlist) 
        }
    }
    return(tokens)
}

make_bigram <- function(words) {
    n1s <- character()
    n2s <- character()

    n1.set <- bigram_list(words, 1)
    n1s <- c(n1s, n1.set)

    n2.set <- bigram_list(words, 2)
    n2s <- c(n2s, n2.set)

    bigrams <- data.frame(n1=n1s, n2=n2s)
    return(bigrams)
}
```

Comment: Do you need only the bigrams or also the counts of those bigrams?

Comment: I need the actual bigrams. I can aggregate them somewhat quickly once I've got them in a data frame, by using a data table. My final goal is a set of bigrams and their frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this in Python is:

```
zip(tokens[:-1],tokens[1:])
```

There's two things there: list slicing and zip.

List slicing lets you cut segments of a list out. In this case, we're actually removing the last and first tokens from the list, respectively, but only selecting all but the last and all but the first tokens in the slice.

`zip` combines both lists, where parallel entries in each list form a tuple; `mapply` in R seems to be similar enough to that for our purposes.

In R, this seems to work:

```
> tokens <- list("I", "am", "a", "banana",".")
> mapply(list,tokens[1:length(tokens)-1], tokens[2:length(tokens)])
     [,1] [,2] [,3]     [,4]    
[1,] "I"  "am" "a"      "banana"
[2,] "am" "a"  "banana" "."
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but how can I get it to work for the entire list? My short test set is:                                                                                        l1 <- c("quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps")
l2 <- c("once", "upon", "midnight", "dreary")
l3 <- c("quoth", "raven", "nevermore")
Li <- list(l1, l2, l3)

Comment: Are your lists individual documents or sentences? You may not want to form bigrams across sentences. There's no reason to form bigrams across documents. As for traversing the individual lists, use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

To get only the bigrams you can use the `ngram` package. It is quite fast because it is written in C. However, the current version seems to only allow exporting the n-grams without their respective frequency.

To also get the frequencies you can use the `tau` package. `textcnt()` can, among other things, return n-grams and their frequencies.

In the benchmark below we can see that `ngram()` is much faster than `textcnt()` but the comparison is not completely fair here since `textcnt()` also calculates the frequencies.

```
text <- list("This is just an example for Stackoverflow",
             "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
             "And another example sentence to test the function",
             "This is the end of the list")
# Repeat to make the list larger
text <- rep(text, 1000)

### Using the tau package --------------------------------
library(tau)
# Find and count n-grams. Treats list elements separately.
# (For example there is no bigram "stackoverflow the")
ngrams <- textcnt(text, method = "string", n = 2L, decreasing = T)
# > head(ngrams, 3)
# this is      an example     and another
# 2000            1000            1000

## Apply over separate list elements
ngrams <- lapply(text, 
                 function(x) textcnt(x, 
                                     method = "string", 
                                     n = 2L, 
                                     decreasing = T))

### Using the ngram package -------------------------------
# This works only on a string, not a list. 
# Does not return frequencies
library(ngram)
ngram <- ngram(paste(unlist(text), collapse = " "), 
               n = 2L)
ngram <- get.ngrams(ngram)
# > head(ngram, 3)
# [1] "just an"     "The quick"   "is the" 

### Benchmarks ---------------------------------------------
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ngram(paste(unlist(text), collapse = " "), 
                              n = 2L))
# mean 34.3, median 33.7
microbenchmark(textcnt(text, method = "string", n = 2L, decreasing = T))
# mean 223.7, median 220.6
```